# Adding a new RequestMapping to kolorobot's spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using the [spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) by kolorobot to start a project using Spring (mostly to learn).

I can build and deploy to tomcat no problem. I've run into a roadblock very early though. I'm having a problem adding a new page. I've created the following class

```
package com.nobodyshero.classroom.about;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AboutController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "about")
    public String about() {
        return "about/about";
    }
}
```

Under webapp / WEB-INF / views I've created a folder named "about" and put an "about.html" inside of it. I can't actually hit it. My web.xml is mostly empty.  As I understand it, the annotations should handle the mapping automatically without me having to define them inside web.xml.

Comment: Has the view resolver been correctly set up? Incidentally, if you are learning Spring then I'd recommend doing it the 'hard' way rather than using a quick-start so you understand how the various Spring configurations work.

Comment: ViewResolver looks OK to me. It's set up using ThymeLeaf. Prefix is WEB-INF/views and suffix is .html. It's working for the RequestMappings that came as part of the archetype, it's just the one I created that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the SecurityConfig class, you have to whitelist the patterns that you can access when not logged in.